# Построение гистограммы с помощью matplotlib

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, matplotlib

Имеется данный код:

```
import sys
import sip

import numpy as np

from PyQt5.Qt import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.plotButton = QPushButton('Plot')

        self.plotButton.clicked.connect(self.plot)

        self.figure = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolBar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.toolBar)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.plotButton)


        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

    def plot(self):
        self.figure.clear()
        data = np.random.randint(1, 3, 10)


        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.bar(np.arange(len(data)), data, align='center')

        self.canvas.draw()        

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

w = Widget()
w.show()        

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Как реализовать добавление подписей снизу на графике, похожее на

```
plt.xticks()
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте методы `set_xticks/set_yticks` или `set_xticklabels/set_yticklabels` класса `AxesSubplot`.